# How to avoid adding same data into database using for loop in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to know how to insert all the rows into db.

HTML code :

```
 <html>
    <label> Selector Name </label>
     <input type="textbox" value="Anu" name="selector_name"/>
    </label> 
    <label> Product Ids </label>
     <input type="textbox" value="1,2,3" name="product_ids"/>
 </html>
```

Python function :

```
        selector =  parms['selector_name']
        product_id = parms['product_ids']
        prodids = product_id.split(",")
        for i in range(0,len(prodids)):
            product = Product.query.filter_by(id=imgids[i]).first_or_404()
            if product:
                product    = ProductSelector([product])
                selector.images.append(product)
         db.session.add(selector)     
         db.session.commit()
```

The above code tries to add same product multiple times, which is not allowed. How can add multiple product without adding the same product.

Traceback :

```
  sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) duplicate key value 
  violates unique constraint "product_selector_pkey"

  DETAIL:  Key (id)=(82) already exists.
 'INSERT INTO product_selector (id) VALUES (%(id)s)' ({'id': 82}, {'id': 
   82}, {'id': 
   82})
```

Comment: Before inserting you can query if the data exists in the database and then add it if not.

Comment: @@user1767754 :  I have many to many relationship tables for a purpose. I cant delete it like that. But I want to reference the product in the into product selector table.

Comment: SQL lets you control what INSERT does on duplicates. The default is to reject, but you can also ignore, or update (I think there's a 4th choice but I can't remember it and can't think what it will do).

Comment: I don't know how to get sqlalchemy to do the different variations of insert, but I'm sure it's in the docs; if not, then you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it when there is an IntegrityError exception. This will skip that record and process the next one and so on when it find this exception. Make sure you iomport the IntergrityError.

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError


    try:
        selector =  parms['selector_name']
        product_id = parms['product_ids']
        prodids = product_id.split(",")
        for i in range(0,len(prodids)):
            product = Product.query.filter_by(id=imgids[i]).first_or_404()
            if product:
                product    = ProductSelector([product])
                selector.images.append(product)
         db.session.add(selector)     
         db.session.commit()
     except IntegrityError:
         print "Duplicate Value entered"
         pass
```

Comment: You should only have to wrap the `db.session.commit` in the `try` block, and make sure to rollback if it fails!

Comment: @@adam Smith : I cant commit after the try block. I have one more while loop which inserts into some other tables.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the tech completely. I just started working with sqlalchemy recently. Isn't it the commit that throws the `IntegrityError`, in which case won't you have to rollback the session (or else the next time you try to commit the session, the same error will be thrown??)

Comment: @AdamSmith you are right.. he does have to rollback to previous commit.

Comment: @Mydoubts if you want to commit later and then rollback because of IntegrityError you will loose all other data added to the db as well, if that fits your business logic then its fine. If not, I am not sure if there is a better way, but you could commit twice once after adding the selector then again after all your other table inserts. Use the exception pass according to your requirements..